# python socket server receiving messages asynchronously

Tags: python, sockets

I want to build a client/server application in python where:

- the client continuously sends data to the server
- the server receives this data asynchronously, i.e. whenever a certain command is run it receives the data, otherwise it ignores it

I have tried to make a sample code to simulate this behavior, but the problem is that when the server tries to receive the packages it receives all the data that has been sent since the last call to "recv".

Question is: is there a way to receive only the last packages, i.e. ignoring what was sent before?

Here is my example code using a stream socket (I've also tried UDP, same behavior)

Server side:

```
import socket
import multiprocessing
import testClient
import time

address = ('localhost', 50000)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(address)

#Start the client
client = multiprocessing.Process(target=testClient.testClient)
client.start()

s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Received connection {}, {}'.format(conn, addr)
print 'Server> receiving data'
data = conn.recv(15)
print 'Server> received data',repr(data)
time.sleep(10)
print 'Server> receiving data'
data = conn.recv(15)
print 'Server> received data',repr(data)
```

Client side:

```
import socket
import time
import numpy

serverAddress = ('localhost', 50000)

def testClient():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('localhost', 50000))
    count = 0
    while True:  
        data = 'Test string %d'%count
        print '>client: sending data',data
        s.sendall(data)
        time.sleep(1)
        count +=1
    s.close()
```

Sample output:

```
>client: sending data Test string 0
Server> receiving data
Server> received data 'Test string 0'
>client: sending data Test string 1
>client: sending data Test string 2
>client: sending data Test string 3
>client: sending data Test string 4
>client: sending data Test string 5
>client: sending data Test string 6
>client: sending data Test string 7
>client: sending data Test string 8
>client: sending data Test string 9
Server> receiving data
Server> received data 'Test string 1Te'
...
```

What I'd like to receive the second time is "Test string 9". Is there a way to do that or is it totally unrealistic?

**EDIT**

Following Mike's answer I realized I might need to close the connection and open a new one when I need to read more data. This solution could be implemented using a datagram socket. Here is my working example:

Server side

```
import socket
import multiprocessing
import testClientUDP
import time


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print 'Server> starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

#Start client process
client = multiprocessing.Process(target = testClientUDP.testClient)
client.start()

data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
print 'Server> received data: ',data

#Close socket
sock.close()

time.sleep(5)
#Open a new socket 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(server_address)

data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
print 'Server> received data: ',data
sock.close()

time.sleep(5)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(server_address)

data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
print 'Server> received data: ',data

sock.close()
```

Client side

```
import socket
import time

def testClient():
    # Create a UDP socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    server_address = ('localhost', 10000)

    try:
        count = 0        
        while True:
            # Send data
            data = 'Test message %d'%count
            print 'Client> sending "%s"' %data
            sent = sock.sendto(data, server_address)
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1

    finally:
        print 'Client> closing socket'
        sock.close()
```

Output

```
Server> starting up on localhost port 10000
Client> sending "Test message 0"
Server> received data: Test message 0
Client> sending "Test message 1"
Client> sending "Test message 2"
Client> sending "Test message 3"
Client> sending "Test message 4"
Client> sending "Test message 5"
Server> received data: Test message 5
Client> sending "Test message 6"
Client> sending "Test message 7"
Client> sending "Test message 8"
Client> sending "Test message 9"
Client> sending "Test message 10"
Server> received data: Test message 10 
Client> sending "Test message 11"
Client> sending "Test message 12"
...
```

Comment: Unrelated: in the edit queue, I came across a question that you voted on in triage. You made the wrong choice there. Please: study the help for triage really carefully, and avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. Please understand that your votes have consequences! This is the one I am talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20889741

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping, to wait for the "desired" message will not work, because it's still the same connection and there is data on the stream that piled up.

**Option 1:**

One way is to call `conn.recv(1024)` (you may use any other value, 1024 works well for most cases) in a while loop, until the stream is "empty" and discard the 8 message blocks that you're not interested in (use a counter variable for that).

**Option 2:**

If you know exactly how much bits have piled up, you can also use `conn.recv(13)` to receive your first message, then sleep and then call `conn.recv(13*8)` (read 8 times your 13 bits messages - this is the data 1-9, that you do not want)  and the next time you read from the stream it will contain your 9th message.

However, this relies heavily on knowlegde how many bits exactly the client will send, so the first option would be better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I see there's no way to get rid of the messages sent in between. Point is there might me a huge amount of data and I don't really care about it, so having to read it all may be too time consuming.

Comment: However your comment made me think that closing the connection after reading and opening a new one when I need to read data might work. Of course it doesn't work for a stream socket, but for a datagram socket this works.